# Vue app (data out of scope) - Data is not defined at Proxy.calc

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, find, defined

*Greetings Stackoverflow peeps.

I am developing my first Vue app and having issues with using the find function to loop through my metals list to pull the specificGravity value based on a matching type prop.
It seems that the list is out of scope and I am unable to find a solution through good ole' Google, so I turn to you all.

TIA*

Error:

"vue@next:1751 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
at Proxy.calc (index.html:101:45)
at onClick (eval at compileToFunction (vue@next:15591:23), :142:35)
at callWithErrorHandling (vue@next:1688:24)
at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (vue@next:1697:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue@next:9486:15)"

```
<script>
        var app = Vue.createApp({
            data: function() {  
                
                
               
                return {
                    
                    waxWeight: null,
                    isVisible: true,
                    buttonSize: null,
                    specificGravity: null,
                    metalType: null
                }
            },    

            // <!-- COMPONENTS -->
            components: {
                    },

            // <!-- METHODS -->
            // `this` inside methods point to the current Vue instance
            methods: {
                calc: function (waxWeight, buttonSize, metalType) {

                    var waxWeight = waxWeight
                    var buttonSize = buttonSize
                    var metalType = metalType

                var metals = {metals:[
                    { type: 'silver', specificGravity: 10.3 },
                    { type: 'wGold14', specificGravity: 12.1 },
                    { type: 'wGold18', specificGravity: 11.5 },
                    { type: 'yGold14', specificGravity: 13.6 }]}

                    // method does not have access to data list 
                    const specificGravity = data.metals.find(function(elem){
                        if(elem.name == metalType) 
                        
                        return elem.specificGravity;

                        alert(metalType)
                    });
                }
            },
        })
        app.mount('#app')
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure what you are trying to do in this function, but I will try to help you.

The problem is data is not accessible like that, data is a function that return a JSON object. So imagine you want to access the isVisible declared in the Data. You use `this.isVisible`.

However I can't understand why you need to access data there. It seems that you want to access the array inside the json object, so try `metals.metals.find(...)`. And if you want to access the array metals, when you are calling elem.name you are always going to get undefined since this is not a key of the object, you should use `elem.type` instead. Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/Toscan00/pen/vYWxOdR) that I made for you to exemplify what I'm saying

Sorry for the long answer, if this not help you please provide more context so I can help you

Comment: Thank you so much XAronX, that was quite helpful.

I am trying to pull the specificGravity value from the metals array in order to use it for calculations.

Here is a CodePen of my current code with updates after your response.

Thanks again for your help. 

https://codepen.io/pandemicprogrammer/pen/GROWqwR

Comment: No problem, if my commentary help you, please consider upvote so other people can be helped too.

If you still need help just ask and will try  to help you

Comment: As soon as I've earned the required 15 rep to do so I absolutely will :-)

Answer (score 0):

Initial issue resolved here: https://codepen.io/pandemicprogrammer/pen/GROWqwR

I was referencing the array object incorrectly and had my JSON data in the wrong spot.

```
methods: {
                calc: function (waxWeight, buttonSize, metalType) {
                    alert("test")

                    var waxWeight = waxWeight
                    var buttonSize = buttonSize
                    var metalType = metalType

                    var metals = {metals:[
                    { type: 'silver', specificGravity: 10.3 },
                    { type: 'wGold14', specificGravity: 12.1 },
                    { type: 'wGold18', specificGravity: 11.5 },
                    { type: 'yGold14', specificGravity: 13.6 }]}


                    const specificGravity = 
                    metals.metals.find(function(elem){
                         
                        if(elem.type == metalType) {
                            
                            alert(elem.specificGravity)
                            return elem.specificGravity;
                        }

                        

                    });
                }
            },
```